# How can I update a dynamically selected json key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to figure out how I can make a generic function that takes a path to a jsonObj using an array, and then update the last key in the array.

PS! This might we the wrong way to do this, so feel free to show other examples on how to solve this.

In the end the data object should be updated.

This is what I have come up with so far

```
    data = {
    'level1_1': {
        'level2_1': {
            'no1': 1,
            'no2': 2
        }
    },
    'level1_2': {
        'level2_2': {
            'no1': 10,
            'no2': 20
        }
    }    
}

var updateJson = function(path, value){
    var a = data;
    path.forEach(function(e){
        a = a[e];
    });
    return a;
};

updateJson(['level1_2','level2_2','no2'], 100);
```

In this example I would like to update the no2 key with the value of 100

Comment: Why not just use the dot notation to update the value? You aren't really benefiting here. You already need to know the precise path the the value to update, so it is really just making the update process even more difficult. `data.level1_2.level2_2.no2 = 100;` and you are done. If you need something to update _all_ `no2` values, well than that would be a different story.

Comment: I should be able to send any path to the function, and update that specific key, thats why I dont use the normal dot notation.

Comment: I still don't get it - it is the same thing? Either way you have to know the specific path. Where is the benefit? Is it to allow you to pass in a bad path without error?

Comment: because this function resides in a angularjs-service(singleton) that holds a jsonObj for me. I need to update this jsonObj from a few different controllers.

Comment: Well, I still think you are over complicating things, but maybe you just aren't explaining it well either. Regardless, the answer gets what you are looking for. Good luck! :)

Comment: Tim, you are right. I'am def. is over complicating things. It was fine to just declare the jsonObj and return it in the service and then just use dot notation. Does the same job as juvians answer, but with less code :) Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with recursion:

```
function updateJson(path,val,obj) {
  if (!obj) obj = data; 
  if (path.length < 2) { 
    obj[path[0]] = val; 
  } else {
    if (!obj[path[0]]) obj[path[0]] = {};
    obj = obj[path.shift()]; 
    updateJson(path,val,obj); 
  }    
}

updateJson(['level1_2','level2_2','no2'], 100); 
console.log(data.level1_2.level2_2.no2)//100
```

Comment: @JoakimB understood wrongly, will make an example in a few minutes

Comment: @JoakimB check new answer

Comment: Solved it. Thank you juvian.